# Hosting a dynamic website built without PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, json

I have a dynamic website built without PHP and MySQL. The data resides in separate array structures within the individual '.html' (in case of sub pages) and within separate '.js' files (for the index page) and are linked to each other.

The folder/file structure is something like below:

**index.html**

**js (folder)**

1. indexmain.js
2. file1.js
3. file2.js, etc...
   (json arrays for main page within the .js files)

**css (folder)**

1. maincssfile.css
2. subpages.css

**SubPages (Folder)**

1. Page1.html
2. Page2.html
3. Page3.html
4. etc...

(The 'json arrays' data for each of the 'sub-pages' resides within the html pages themselves).

The website works perfectly fine on the localhost using 'xampp'. However now when I need to load it on a host machine like 'godaddy.com'. Will it still work smoothly or will I face issues die to the structure I am using? Can I still secure my data without opting for PHP and mySQL?

Looking forward to your inputs.

Comment: _"Can I still secure my data"_ - what do you mean, "still"? What exactly do you think you have "secured" right now?

Comment: yes, your website will work perfectly. But you need PHP and MySQL for server-side residence.

Comment: @Dean - "Server-side residence" would mean? Sorry, I'm still new at this and learning one step at a time. After I get a domain name and upload my files on the hosting machine through, say 'godaddy.com', would I be required to do anything further to take it live?